# How can I set the first radio button in RecyclerView checked with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I use the Code A to create a RecyclerView with radio button based some searched sample code from website.

1、I don't know if these code is good, is there a better way to implement radio button in RecyclerView?

2、How can I set the first radio button checked default when I start the APP? You know that none of radio button is checked when I start the APP.

**Code A**

```
class CustomAdapter (val backupItemList: List<MSetting>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var mSelectedItem = -1

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    fun getSelectedItem():Int{
        return  mSelectedItem
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(backupItemList[position])
        holder.itemView.radioButton.setChecked(position == mSelectedItem);
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return backupItemList.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bindItems(aMSetting: MSetting) {
           itemView.radioButton.tag=aMSetting._id
            itemView.textViewUsername.text=aMSetting.createdDate.toString()
            itemView.textViewAddress.text=aMSetting.description

            itemView.radioButton.setOnClickListener {
                mSelectedItem=getAdapterPosition()
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


               <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My First" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUsername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Belal Khan"
                />

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Ranchi, Jharkhand"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I have on question here... There will be list of RBs in your list and can only one will be selected at a time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    private var mSelectedItem = -1
```

...

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindItems(backupItemList[position], position, mSelectedItem)
}
```

...

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
fun bindItems(aMSetting: MSetting, position: Int, selectedPosition: Int) {
    itemView.radioButton.tag=aMSetting._id
    itemView.textViewUsername.text=aMSetting.createdDate.toString()
    itemView.textViewAddress.text=aMSetting.description

    if ((selectedPosition == -1 && position == 0))
        itemView.radioButton.setChecked(true)
    else        
        if (selectedPosition == position)
            itemView.radioButton.setChecked(true)
        else
            itemView.radioButton.setChecked(false)


            itemView.radioButton.setOnClickListener {
                mSelectedItem=getAdapterPosition()
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the first `RadioButton` in your list to be true, you can check the adapterPosition and if it is 0 (i.e. first item) set it to true.

**For example:**

```
class CustomAdapter
{
    var mSelectedItem = 0

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            fun bindItems(aMSetting: MSetting) {
               ....

                if(adapterPosition == mSelectedItem)
                    itemView.radioButton.checked = true
                else
                    itemView.radioButton.checked = false
            }
        }
}
```